# Create Uniform Buffers in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, vulkan

i hava a problem with drawing meshes in Vulkan.
I want to bind a UniformBufferObject in the following form to a Object.

```
void mainLoop() {
     ..
     vulkanDrawing.Draw();
     plane.UpdateUniformBuffers();
     ..
}
```

To get the currentImage, I created a method SetCurrentImage(uint32_t currentImage).
SetCurrentImage is set from VulkanDrawing::Draw() Method.
This current image is used in the UpdateUniformBuffers().
I get only a black screen if I run this application. 
Since, I want to see a square.
In the past, I called the UpdateUniformBuffers Method with an imageIndex parameter in VulkanDrawing::Draw().
I think it could be a problem with the fences or semaphores. But I don't know how I shall fix it.
Does I use eventually a wrong Architecture?

I have attached important Methods:

```
void CVulkanDrawing::Draw()
{
    vkWaitForFences(m_LogicalDevice.getDevice(), 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());
    vkResetFences(m_LogicalDevice.getDevice(), 1,inFlightFences[currentFrame]);

    uint32_t imageIndex;
    vkAcquireNextImageKHR(m_LogicalDevice.getDevice(), m_Presentation.GetSwapChain(), std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max(), imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_VulkanMesh.size(); i++)
    {
        //m_VulkanMesh.at(i).UpdateUniformBuffers(imageIndex);
        m_VulkanMesh.at(i).SetCurrentImage(imageIndex);
    }

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};

    ...

    currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
}

void CVulkanMesh::UpdateUniformBuffers()
{
    ...

    vkMapMemory(m_LogicalDevice.getDevice(), uniformBuffersMemory[this->m_CurrentImage], 0, sizeof(ubo), 0, &data);
    memcpy(data, &ubo, sizeof(ubo));
    vkUnmapMemory(m_LogicalDevice.getDevice(), uniformBuffersMemory[this->m_CurrentImage]);
}

void CVulkanMesh::SetCurrentImage(uint32_t currentImage)
{
     this->m_CurrentImage = currentImage;
}
```

I have additionally created a branch named: https://github.com/dekorlp/VulkanWrapper/tree/VulkanTest

I hope you can help me :)

Best regards

Pixma

Comment: Have you got anything other than a black screen before? There's many reasons you might just get a black image, what makes you think it's related to how you're using uniform buffers?

Comment: yes, before I the screen has shown a square. The black screen is visible virstly after I changed the code, to the following form, Above. The strange is, the imageIndex passed to the VulkanMesh has the correct value, but the square is not showed.

Comment: I changed it and it functionate now.
But I didn't like this solution.
I gave the Class a method which returns the actual Image to draw: CVulkanDrawing::GetCurrentImageToDraw().
This image is passed to the UpdateUniformBuffers method in the render while.
     void mainLoop() {
          ..
          vulkanDrawing.Draw();
          plane.UpdateUniformBuffers(vulkanDrawing.GetCurrentImageToDraw());
           ..
     }

I am thinking actually about creating a large struct which cointains important informations like the Vulkan Instance, PhysicalDevice, LogicalDevice,
But is this good?

Comment: "Why doesn't this work" and "how should I structure my code" are different; StackOverflow probably isn't the best place to answer the latter as it's more subjective. Personally, I think having a root "GPU Context" object that contains the instance, physical device, logical device, queues, memory manager, etc. makes sense to me.